# C++ - Making the console fullscreen?

Tags: c++, windows-7, mingw, fullscreen, codeblocks

All right, I'm sad now. Microsoft has removed the fullscreen console feature from Win7, which is what I'm running. Now I'm looking into things like OpenGL or SDL to see if I can emulate the console, and make it fullscreen (and I mean FULLSCREEN no window or border or anything). Is it possible to emulate the console fullscreen (like DOS) in OpenGL or something similar?

Comment: You can just make a regular fullscreen window; you don't need OpenGL.

Comment: So I'd use the console's HWND, remove the border and title bar, and then resize it?

Comment: if want to simulate console with OpenGL(don't know why you want to do that, drawing texts with OpenGL is not so trivial), use [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html).

Answer (score 4):

try the system command it's a bit esier (system ("mode 650"); } example:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
int main(){
system("mode 650");
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the tag of mingw, so probably you don't like me to propose Cygwin. With cygwin you can do Alt+shift+Enter to get full screen. And with cygwin you can also run DOS script. Since I only used it at XP before, I am not very sure about that it works in 7.

Check this link: http://forums.mydigitallife.info/archive/index.php/t-21673.html, mainly focus on **blinkomatic**'s comment. He said it can be done by Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Windows XP you cant a console fullscreen, Microsoft removed the functionality (WDDM display drivers)

You can use http://www.dosbox.com/ to fullscreen DOS applications

Answer (score 0):

Go to device manager and disable the display adapters, the resolution gets changed. Now You can use the c++ in full screen mode. You can restore it back by enable the display adapters.