# Failed to create a fuilscreen console window in C

Tags: c, winapi, fullscreen, mingw32

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#include <windows.h>

int main() 
{
    HWND StdHandle = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleDisplayMode (StdHandle, CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, 0);
    system ("pause");
}
```

[The **Community Additions** written by Jim Michaels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686028(v=vs.85).aspx) said that if  your app requires windows 7, you must add `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601` at the top of your files just before the #includes.

But [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136256/c-making-the-console-fullscreen) said that Microsoft removed the functionality (WDDM display drivers).

Which is correct?

My aim is to create a fuilscreen console window, but eventually failed. Why?

Comment: I try to improve my answer skills. Please tell me why you accepted but not upvoted, I will do better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Seven:

```
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdHandle = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    BOOL bWin32Ret = SetConsoleDisplayMode (hStdHandle, CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, 0);
    if ( bWin32Ret == 0 )
    {
        DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError(); // 120
    }
}
```

`winerror.h` excerpt

```
// This function is not supported on this system.
//
#define ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED       120L
```

using `#define` for `_WIN32_WINNT` won't change anything.